# Meaning of time output from stat

Tags: unix, ext4, stat

I stat a file on ext4 filesystem, and get the following output:

```
2016-09-09 14:36:21.269384800
```

What is the meaning of 269384800? Is it nanoseconds, or something else?

Comment: Related SO question: [timestamp accuracy on EXT4 (sub millsecond)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14392975/timestamp-accuracy-on-ext4-sub-millsecond)

Comment: [stat(2) - Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) "Since kernel 2.5.48, the stat structure supports nanosecond resolution for the three file timestamp fields."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in the date `2016-09-09 14:36:21.269384800` The portion/number *`.269384800`* is referring to nanoseconds.

As *DavidPostill* mentions in his comment, starting on **kernel 2.5.48** the `stat` structure does support nanosecond resolution for the three file timestamp fields. You can read the complete details from the man page here: http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat

Comment: Thanks! The full output is:  Birth: 2016-09-09 14:36:21.269384800 -0500. What does -0500 here mean?

Comment: That is your time zone offset. In the case of `-0500`, `stat` is giving you the offset for the displayed date. In this case is GMT -5 hours. You can see an interactive map with global time zones here: [https://www.timeanddate.com/time/map/](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/map/)